# How do I get Beautiful Soup to read the contents of Selenium web driver?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape news headlines with python, beautiful soup and selenium from a website with a "show more" button. I am able to successfully load the page with selenium, click the button to bring up more headlines, and then print out the headlines, all with no error messages. My problem is Beautiful Soup is not reading the contents of the driver after the "show more" button is clicked. It is only reading the headlines that are initially on the page before the button is clicked. How do I make it so the the headlines are read and printed out only after the "show more" button is click a certain number of times? I have a for loop rather than a while loop to so I can click the button n times.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s=Service('/Users/comp/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.foxnews.com/politics'
driver.get(url)

for x in range(10):
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/section[4]/footer/div/a")
        time.sleep(3)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('h4')
for x in headlines:
    print(x.text.strip())

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Just reading your code, it looks like you're getting the URL, clicking loadMoreButton 10 times, and then printing the headlines from the URL. I wouldn't expect `driver.find_element()` to do anything but find the element. I haven't used BeautifulSoup much or Selenium ever so I could be way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Now it's working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s=Service('./chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.foxnews.com/politics'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

for x in range(10):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('h4')
        for x in headlines:
            print(x.text.strip())

            
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/section[4]/footer/div/a")
            
        if loadMoreButton:
            loadMoreButton.click()
            time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```